# Check website speed using Firebug

Tags: performance, website, speed, firebug

I was using the “Net” panel of Firebug to check my website speed. I have a timer on the server script and it only takes around 0.02 seconds, but dang is it slow to render the page (6 seconds). Then I closed Firebug, and it rendered almost instantly. How should I use Firebug to accurately check the speed of a website?

Answer (score 1):

Recording the network traffic data takes some time, which results in a slowdown of the page load. Though normally this slowdown isn't that big.

Note that the 20ms you measured only refers to the time needed to generate the page script. It doesn't take all the other requests into account involved into the page load, e.g. CSS, JavaScripts, images, etc.

I suggest you compare Firebug's *Net* panel output with the one of the [Firefox DevTools' *Network* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). If they differ much, disable the *Console* and *Script* panel and check if that makes any difference. If not, you may [file a bug against Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues).